# Sql query to determine income statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a Python script to insert data from a Excel file to a MySQL database. I am looking for a query to measure each branch and division its profitability. I have e.g. the following data:

```
Ledger account              Name           Debit    Credit  Branch  Division
                    
610020                     Rent building    150                BXL  WPL
615200                     Telephone        250                BXL  WPL
                    
700100                    Turnover parts             1050      BXL  WPL
700100                    Turnover parts    50                 BXL  WPL
                    
700110                    Work hours                 500       BXL  WPL
700110                    Work hours                 300       BXL  WPL
```

I would like to get an income statement for the branch and division involved. For each ledger account I would like to know its total debit or credit amount.

This I what I would like to see for branch 'BXL' and division 'WPL' by using SQL:

```
                             Debit  Credit
            
610020  Rent building      150,00   
615200  Telephone           250,00  
700100  Turnover parts              1.000,00
700110  Work hours                  800,00
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Hello I already have the basic query now, the income statement is being generated.

```
 LEDGER_ACCOUNT, Name SUM(Debet) AS Debet, SUM(Credit) AS Credit
FROM boekingen
WHERE Branch = 'BXL'
AND Division = 'WPL'
GROUP BY
LEDGER_ACCOUNT
```

Now I have to integrate the case statement because each entry for ledger account should have either a debet or credit value.

```
CASE WHEN Debet > Credit THEN Debet - Credit ELSE '' END AS Debet
CASE WHEN Credit > Debet THEN Credit - Debet ELSE '' END AS Credit
```

When I'm trying to merge I receive a SQL syntax error. What's wrong with this code?

```
SELECT 
 LEDGER_ACCOUNT, Name SUM(Debet) AS Debet, SUM(Credit) AS Credit
CASE WHEN Debet > Credit THEN Debet - Credit ELSE '' END AS Debet
CASE WHEN Credit > Debet THEN Credit - Debet ELSE '' END AS Credit
FROM boekingen
WHERE Branch = 'BXL'
AND Division = 'WPL'
GROUP BY
LEDGER_ACCOUNT
```

Thx.

Comment: Sounds like straight-forward `SUM()` with `GROUP BY`.  What seems to be a problem?

Comment: I don't have a basic knowledge of SQL ...

Comment: I guess it's a good time to get some. You can practice in [SQL Zoo](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SUM_and_COUNT) or any other similar place.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some CTEs to try and get you started. This is not the most optimal way of doing it so if this is for work then I would recommend doing some research to make it better

```
WITH CTE_1
AS
(
SELECT
    LEDGER_ACCOUNT,
    NAME,
    SUM(DEBIT) AS DEBIT,
    SUM(CREDIT) AS CREDIT,
    BRANCH,
    DIVISION
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY
    LEDGER_ACCOUNT,
    NAME,
    BRANCH,
    DIVISION
)
SELECT
    LEDGER_ACCOUNT,
    NAME,
    CASE WHEN DEBIT > CREDIT THEN DEBIT - CREDIT ELSE '' END AS DEBIT
    CASE WHEN CREDIT > DEBIT THEN CREDIT - DEBIT ELSE '' END AS CREDIT
FROM CTE_1
```